# unsigned long long won't store big numbers

Tags: c++

I'm confused with the C/C++ `unsigned long long` type because theoretically it should store up to 2^64-1 which is a number of 19 decimal digits, but the following code:

```
unsigned int x = 1000000u; //(One million)
unsigned long long k = (x*x);
cout << k << endl;
```

prints out 3567587328, which is not correct.
Now 1,000,000^2 results in 1,000,000,000,000 - a number of 12 decimal digit, way below the limit of even `signed long long`. How could this happen?
Does it have anything to do with the system I am running? (32-bit Ubuntu)

If I need a 64 bit system to implement a 64 bit operation then another question arises:
Most compilers use linear congruential generator to generate random numbers as follow:

```
x(t) = (a*x(t-1) + c) mod m.
```

`a` and `c` is usually a 32 bit big number, m is `2^32-1`
So there is a big chance that `a*x(t-1)` results in a 64-bit number before the modulo operation is carried out.

If a 64 bit system is needed then how could gcc generate random numbers since 1990s on 16-32bit machines?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Change x to long long and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is `unsigned int` --> `x*x` is `unsigned int` as well. In case the result of the multiplication exceeds the maximal value of `unsigned int`, wraparound occurs. **Only after these** operations the result is being assigned into the receiving variable (`k`). If you want the result to be `unsigned long long` you need to promote at least one of the operand to this type, e.g.: `unsigned long long k = (unsigned long long)x * x;`.

Regarding your second question: compilers usually do not generate numbers, that's done during runtime. I'm not sure where did you get the formulae `x(t) = (a*x(t-1) + c) mod m`. Assuming this is indeed the formula there are ways to keep the intermediate results bounded: the modulo operation can be applied to any operand or intermediate result without changing the outcome. Therefore `x(t) = (a*x(t-1) + c) mod m = (a mod m) * (x(t-1) mod m) + c mod m`.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic.
Btw the formula is being used in many compilers with different parameters as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

Sure `k` is `unsigned long long`, but `x` is `unsigned int` and hence so is `x*x`. Your expression is calculated as an `unsigned int`, which results in the usual wraparound when going over the limits of unsigned types. After the damage is done, it is converted to an `unsigned long long`.

Possible fixes:

- make `x` an `unsigned long long`
- `unsigned long long k = ((unsigned long long)x*(unsigned long long)x);`
- `unsigned long long k = (1ULL*x*x);`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've never been taught that the result of `int*int` will be wrapped around an `int` before assigned to other variable.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply an `unsigned int` by an `unsigned int` on the right side, the result is an `unsigned int`.  As such it has the same limits as the two numbers being multiplied, regardless of the fact that this value is subsequently assigned to an `unsigned long long`.

However, if you cast the `unsigned int` variables to `unsigned long long`, the result will be an `unsigned long long` and the value will not be limited to the size of an `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned long long k = (((unsigned long long)x)*((unsigned long long)x));
```

That should give you the result you want.